# OCaml "to" keyword?

Tags: ocaml, keyword

I was writing some OCaml code, and noticed my syntax highlighting treated `to` in a special way. So I fired up my OCaml repl ([utop](https://github.com/ocaml-community/utop)) and tried to instantiate a variable with the name `to`.

```
let to = 1;;
```

and I get a SyntaxError with the `to` underlined. I also tried to see if it was an operator,

```
(to);;
```

but that also raised a SyntaxError. **I'm wondering: what is the `to` keyword, and is there a full list of OCaml keywords?**

Comment: Looks like it's part of a range/for syntax http://rigaux.org/language-study/syntax-across-languages-per-language/OCaml.html

Comment: @Carcigenicate Ahhhhh there it is. I was sure it looked a bit familiar. I tried some (1 to 2) stuff but that also was a syntax error. Thanks a ton. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Np. Btw, I searched "Ocaml reserved words" to find it. "reserved word" seems to be a more common term than "keyword".

Comment: @Awesome, thanks for the advice. I'll try to use that term from now on.

Comment: fwiw, the manual contains a list of keywords (http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it's part of a [range/for-loop syntax](http://rigaux.org/language-study/syntax-across-languages-per-language/OCaml.html):

The example given in the link:

```
for i = 1 to 10 do ... done
```